# Best way to demo while ISV Partner agreement in-process

Tags: isv, beta-managed-package

We are working through the process to become an ISV but we have an app written.  (I know, backwards)  We would like to run demos with clients to show them that we are on track.

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need tons of data for your app, less than 2,500 records, simply create a developer edition and install.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like the best way.  Client will have to understand that it is a throw-away just for playing.